# Select an int column where '1001-1001' = 1001?

Tags: sql

When executing

```
SELECT item_id FROM (`phppos_items`) WHERE `item_id` = '1001-1001'
```

I get back this row

1001

item_id is an int auto-incrementing column. How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: What do you want to get back from that query?

Comment: If item_id is an int, then why would it ever be equal to '1001-1001'?

Comment: How do you prevent what from happening?

Comment: It probably tries to convert '1001-1001' to an int and comes up with 1001

Comment: MySQL, presumably? If so, please tag it as such, if not, please tag with whichever DBMS you are using.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Are any other DBMSes crazy enough to use ` as a quote character?

Comment: @Flimzy - I'm not aware of any, but I've been fooled enough times that I don't like guessing about anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`item_id` is an integer column.

Therefore, when you compare it to a string (`'1001-1001'`), this string is converted to an integer. The string `'1001-1001'` is converted to the integer `1001`, so it matches the column you got back.

As for how to avoid it, it depends on what you're trying to do. If you're trying to find a row having the id `'1001-1001'`, that just won't exist, as the column contains only integers.

If you're trying to find all ids inside of a range, try using the [`BETWEEN ... AND ...` operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) instead:

```
SELECT item_id FROM (`phppos_items`) WHERE `item_id` BETWEEN 1001 AND 1001
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't quote things that aren't strings.

Comment: This is not a helpful/complete answer. If he were to remove the quotes, he'd be searching for item_id 0, which also wouldn't help him.

Comment: This was actually a bit helpful as I was able to check in php if is_numeric then cast to an int otherwise use -1.